# Talent agents who call out of the blue

Tags: interviewing

I applied to a job posting that was 27 days old but figured "why not?" and wanted to do it regardless.

Two weeks later I received a call from a talent agent at the company who stated the usual - good fit and skills and to call them back - which I did.

I left a message and mentioned that I had a specific time the next day when I could talk and I would try then. If that was not a good time, they could email me times of availability and we could work out a time then.

I called the next day and got voice mail and left a message again saying that we could setup a time and to email me as to not play phone tag. I thanked them for their time and then got a call back a few hours later stating that they were flat out in meetings and they would call me back in a few hours.

I am beginning to be a tad off put as my suggestion of using email to schedule a time to talk is being ignored which seems odd, especially when I mentioned I was in and out of meetings myself all day.

As I am currently employed and can’t just hop outside to take a quick call at any time, I do find it a bit off putting and pushy that they continue to call and leave messages rather than reach out via email and ask for some days and times to do an initial phone screen.

I wouldn’t mind some input as I haven’t experienced a situation like this - even head hunters have emailed me first prior to calling.

Comment: Is abandoning this talent agency an option? In the US, there are *tons* of them, and sometimes companies will use several agencies to help find talent for the same/similar openings. I don't want to answer in a comment, but my opninion is that I would disengage from this agency and either A) Apply to the company which truly holds the job opening directly, or B) Try to find a different talent agency to facilitate your goals.

Comment: Ironically it's a talent acquisition branch of the company I had applied to, not a head hunter from another agency. This branch happens to be in a different part of the country, not where I had applied to but is still a part of the company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the approach of no longer using telephonic communication and strictly using email to "return their call." (if you have their email)

If the behavior continues, they either aren't a fan of email or some other reason, but regardless they aren't respecting your wishes - which for me would be a turnoff. At this point, if I *really* wanted this position I would ask if there is someone else who you could work with to facilitate your goals of exploring/applying to this new opportunity who is a more flexible and can use email or call you only when you've specified your availability. I'm not sure how this will affect this process, but anything is better than asking someone for something simple and them ignoring it.

Comment: I was never provided an email address, just a phone number, regardless of my stating to email directly in two voice mails. It isn't that I wanted to not communicate via phone, I just have never encountered someone who blatantly ignored my wishes and to not waste any further time.

Comment: I think you're right to have the feeling of your wishes not being respected. You put it very simply: Call me between X-Y, if I don't answer then just email me. (paraphrasing) This comes off as them being exceptionally lazy and the fact that they were in a meeting doesn't appeal as a valid excuse to ignore your wishes.

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry about it.

HR is a gatekeeper.  They're also a cost center, not a profit center, and their chunk of company resources reflects that.

It's not unusual for HR reps to not be highly functional and to also be extremely busy.  None of that reflects on what your experience would be like inside the company.

Comment: I’m sure it isn’t a reflection of the company though I was sent someone else’s offer letter once from a company I had once worked at from their recruiting staff. Company was disorganized internally but this could have been a one off.

For this particular instance however when you have to mention emailing as to best setup a time yet the person continues to call, certainly makes it difficult to even get the process started less raise suspicion in your current role always leaving the floor for missed calls.